# Date not today or before and not more than year from today check php

Tags: php, date, compare

i need to check and give error if any of these criterion are true:
the date selected by user is:

- today's OR
- Before today's OR
- After 1 year from today

I am checking in this code

```
if((strtotime($_POST["sch_date"])<=strtotime(date("d/m/Y"))) OR (((strtotime(date("d/m/Y",strtotime("+1 year"))))-(strtotime($_POST["sch_date"])))/(60*60*24)<0))
```

but this give haphazard results meaning it shows error if the selected date is 2 days less than 1 year. Can someone please advice how to go about this?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`DateTime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) makes this easy as they are comparable:

```
$dateSelected   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '18/04/2014'); // put your date here
$today          = new DateTime();
$oneYearFromNow = new DateTime('+1 year');
if ($dateSelected <= $today && $dateSelected > $oneYearFromNow) {
    // we're good
}
else {
    // it's the end of the world!
}
```

Comment: hi i am using d/m/Y format. So should i write something like for selected date `new DateTime($_POST["sch_date"])` and for current date `new DateTime('d/m/Y')` ?

Comment: You'll want to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to make sure the date is not ambiguous then. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: thnks @John Conde this seens to work. but i'll try it out more extensively and check

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt was pretty close, maybe just a little over-complicated, try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); // Set your timezone

// Assuming $_POST['sch_date'] is in the form 'd/m/Y'
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['sch_date']);

if (strtotime($date) <= strtotime('today') || strtotime($date) > strtotime('+ 1 year'))
    echo "error";
```

Note: This assumes `$date` is a date in some standard format - `m/d/Y` or `d-m-Y` or `Y-m-d` etc., but not a datetime. See [here for standard formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#91165) It will give an error if `$date` is
today or any date before today, or if `$date` is after 1 year from today.

To convert your non-standard `d/m/y`, you need this, which has been added to the code above:

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $_POST['sch_date']);
```

Comment: hi still same unpredictable results. gives error even when 13/03/2015. Maybe something else is off. Can i force a format for selected date. I am getting it from a javascript

Comment: Edit - Yes, you're right. Was just testing this and it seems to be coverting `d/m/Y` to `m/d/Y`, so maybe you do need to specify. I am running some more tests...

Comment: @user2649343 Note my edits. This should now work for you, given a format of `d/m/Y`